# What is the exception handling when the view's variable is "Undefined variable" in the laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'll call the translationRecord as an Ajax when I need it will be called. However, an error occurs before the request because there is no value. That's why I want to know how to make an exception.

```
 @if(isset($translationRecords))
    @foreach($translationRecords as $translationRecord)                            
       <tr>
          <td id="recodeValue{{ $translationRecord->id }}" style="display:none">{{ $translationRecord->id }}</td>                         
          <td>{{ $translationRecord->korean }}</td>   
          <td>{{ $translationRecord->japanese }}</td>
          <td><button id="recodeRemoveBtn{{ $translationRecord->id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right">삭제</button></td>  
       </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

I always want to load a page that is not a component click on a button for that data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
        url: '{{route('translation.recodes')}}',
        type: 'post',
        data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('ok');

        }, error: function () {
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

"**$translationRecords**"
this present, that ajax code is not always able to retrieve data.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your setup? You are telling us you make an ajax request but you give us your blade code. Or do you return the results of your blade code?

Comment: You'll need to show us where in the Controller you are handling the code that is then passed to your View. You can always add exception handling within the controller that is handling that particular data. But without knowing that information, I'm not sure anyone can be of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $.ajax is a little overpowered. $.post will do just fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post(`{{route('translation.recodes')}}`, {_token : `{{csrf_token()}}`, () => {
       //the post is successfull
    }).fail(() => {
       //the post failed
    });
});
```

A few other options are available

```
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

Check out the docs here
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/